# Display Tag to use Link in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am using display tag (Struts2)to populate values. Please refer my code.

```
<display:table name="sessionScope.studentList" export="true" requestURI="StudentDisplay">   
    <display:column property="studentFullName" title="Name"></display:column>
    <display:column property="studentMobile" title="Mobile No"></display:column>
    <display:column property="studentResidence" title="Residence No"></display:column>
    <display:column property="studentEmail" title="Email"></display:column>
    <display:column property="studentAddress" title="Address"></display:column>                 
    <display:column url="testAction.action"  title="Map"  value="Map Course">       </display:column>
</display:table>
```

what i want is the last column i.e Map should contain a link as Map Course and on click of that i should get the details of the record selected. for eg. the studentId of that particular record. 
Please help me in doing this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html for the tag reference.

You should be able to use the paramId and paramProperty attributes:

```
<display:column url="testAction.action" paramId="id" paramProperty="studentId" title="Map"  value="Map Course"/>
```

This should generate a link with the following URL: testAction.action?id=, provided there is a getStudentId() method in the bean.

But generally, I prefer generating my links inside the display:column tag:

```
<display:table ... id="theCurrentStudent">
    ...
    <display:column title="Map">
        <a href="<c:url value="testAction.action"/>
                     <c:param name="id" value="${theCurrentStudent.studentId}"/>
                 </c:url>">Click here</a>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

You could use any other tag inside the column tag to generate your link. The important thing is that the id attribute of the table tag allows defining a pageContext variable representing the current element of the iteration.